# How to customize Mapbox's NavigationView

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I would like to implement my turn-by-turn navigation app with the help of Mapbox SDK.
If I use their navigationView, its not really customizable, I can only set the colors.
I tried to use MapView with MapBoxNavigation, but the route display is not refreshing after progress change.

```
private void startNavigation(DirectionsRoute route) {
    if (locationComponent != null) {
        navigation = new MapboxNavigation(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
        navigation.addProgressChangeListener(new ProgressChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChange(Location location, RouteProgress routeProgress) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "progress: " + routeProgress.distanceTraveled(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        navigation.addMilestoneEventListener(new MilestoneEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMilestoneEvent(RouteProgress routeProgress, String instruction, Milestone milestone) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "instruction: " + instruction, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        LocationEngine locationEngine = LocationEngineProvider.getBestLocationEngine(this);
        navigation.setLocationEngine(locationEngine);
        navigationMapRoute.addProgressChangeListener(navigation);
        navigationMapRoute.addRoute(route);
        navigation.startNavigation(route);
        camera = new NavigationCamera(mapboxMap, navigation, locationComponent);
        camera.start(route);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/817 I have the same issue. The link above referenced an example activity, EmbeddedNavigationActivity, that is supposed to show this, but I can't seem to find the actual file anywhere in the repository. Maybe you'll have better luck. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/2489 ^This shows it was tagged for migration but whether it's been migrated, deleted, or lost, who knows.